# Is there a pressure differential between the skin and any parts inside the human body?

Tags: pressure, biophysics

Since most of the human body is never directly exposed to the atmosphere, is there a meaningful difference in pressure between any internal organs and the skin?

If so, how do open wounds which expose the internal organs affect the body from a pressure point of view? If not - why not?

I am not sure if the questions is suitable for here, but as I am interested from a more physical point of view, I've posted it. Please let me know should this not be the case and/or vote accordingly.

Comment: Not directly what you asked, but that might be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onychophora

Comment: Cross-posted from [Health](http://health.stackexchange.com/q/4264/). Please don't do this.

Comment: My apologies - I initially submitted to Health but received an error while on a mobile device, and I assumed it did not go through while not verifying... What is the accepted way of rectifying this?

Comment: It's not a physics but a physiology question. The obvious physical answer is, yes, otherwise there would be nothing to hold your liquids and soft tissues inside the body against their own hydrostatic pressure.

Comment: That is true, but what I had in mind while posting the question was how the pressure of certain body parts compares to normal atmospheric pressure, perhaps as a calculated number - if available.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about human physiology not physics, though for the record Google [blood pressure](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=blood+pressure).

Comment: Cross-posted: http://health.stackexchange.com/q/4264/114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So not directly exposed.  The human body is not air tight.  More important the human body is not rigid. Your body will be compressed.  Most of the organs are behind the stomach.

The pressure inside your lungs is slightly lower when you breath in and slightly higher when you breath out.  You lungs must immediate adjust to any pressure difference.

When you pass gas you produce a pressure slightly higher.

Consider bends in diving.  That is because of the pressure of the blood reduces too rapidly.

Since blood is taking in and expelling gases what goes on inside has to be in sync with what is happening on the outside.